# Let $S=(a,b,c,d)$ and $T(S_i)=S_{i+1}=(|a-b|,|b-c|,|c-d|,|d-a|)$. Show that $\max S_i > \max S_{i+4}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, proof-writing, contest-math

Let $S=(a,b,c,d)$ where $a,b,c,d$ are integers $\geq 0$, $T(S_i)=S_{i+1}=(|a-b|,|b-c|,|c-d|,|d-a|)$. Show that $\max S_i > \max S_{i+4}$ as long as $\max S_i > 0$.

---

I can easily show that $\max S_i \geq \max S_{i+1}$ by noting that $\max S_i - 0 \geq \max S_i - x$ for any integer $x\geq 0$. This implies that $\max S_i \geq \max S_{i+4}$.

Non-rigourously, I suspect that $\max S_i = \max S_{i+4}$ will imply that $\max S_i = 0$ since $T$ "loops" the elements around. However it seems like it'll be very tedious (I'll have to prove the case when there are 1/2/3/4 elements = $\max S_i$ and also keep track of where "maximum goes to" depending on if $|a-b|$ or $|d-a| = \max S_i$).

I'll appreciate if someone can give me a hint on how to approach this cleanly!

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be the largest integer, and $b$ be the larger of it's 2 neighbors, $d$ be the other neighbor, and $c$ be the one opposite it.

**Hint:** Split into cases of

- $a \geq b \geq c \geq d $
- $ a \geq c \geq b \geq d$   -> In particular, $S_4 = (0,0,0,0)$.
- $a \geq b \geq d \geq c$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose for a contradiction that $\max S_i = \max S_{i+4}$ with $\max S_i > 0$. Since each element is only affected by the element next to it (mod $4$) for each iteration, WLOG let $a$ be the largest element in $S_i=(a,b,c,d)$.

$S_{i+1} = (|a-b|,|b-c|,|c-d|,|d-a|)$. For the max to be propagated, at least one of $b, d$ must be $0$.

- If $b=0$, then

  $$
  \begin{align}
  S_{i+1} &= (a, c, |c-d|, a-d) \\
  S_{i+2} &= (a-c, |c-|c-d||, ||c-d|-|a-d||, d)
  \end{align}$$

  For the max to be propagated, we have either both $c=d=0$ or $c=0$. If $c=d=0$, then
  $$
  \begin{align}
  S_{i+2} &= (a, 0, a, 0)\\
  S_{i+3} &= (a, a, a, a)\\
  S_{i+4} &= (0,0,0,0)
  \end{align}$$

  If instead only $c=0$, then

  $$
  \begin{align}
  S_{i+2} &= (a, d, a, d)\\
  S_{i+3} &= (a-d, a-d, a-d, a-d)\\
  S_{i+4} &= (0,0,0,0)
  \end{align}
  $$

  So, $b=0\implies \max S_{i+4}=0$.
- If $d=0$, then
  $$
  \begin{align}
  S_{i+1} &= (a-b,|b-c|,c,a) \\
  S_{i+2} &= (|a-b-|b-c||, ||b-c|-c|, a-c, b)\\
  \end{align}$$

  For the max to be propagated, we have either both $b=c=0$ or $c=0$. From before, we know $b=c=0$ cannot be true. If instead only $c=0$, then $S_{i+2} = (a, b, a, b)$ which we also know will lead to $S_{i+4}=(0,0,0,0)$.

  So, $d=0\implies \max S_{i+4}=0$.

Since we must have $\max S_i > 0$, $\max S_{i} > \max S_{i+4}$.